# Allow duplicate slugs for posts on Custom post type in different categories/taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

i'm making a photo gallery for a plastic surgery website, with before and after photos of patients. i made a custom post type /photo-gallery and a taxonomy /procedures, [after reading this post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/insert-category-of-taxonomy-between-custom-post-type-and-post) i was able to include the taxonomy in the permalink, now i want to be able to generate permalinks like

```
www.site.com/photo-gallery/facelift/patient-1
www.site.com/photo-gallery/liposuction/patient-1
www.site.com/photo-gallery/breast-augmentation/patient-1
```

But instead i got a permalink like.

```
www.site.com/photo-gallery/facelift/patient-1
www.site.com/photo-gallery/liposuction/patient-1-2
www.site.com/photo-gallery/breast-augmentation/patient-1-3
```

is there a way to achieve permalinks like in the first group?

Comment: Can you use a hierarchical post type instead of a taxonomy/post type combo? That would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to use a single hierarchical post type instead of a taxonomy/non-hierarchical post type combination. A hierarchical post type allows you to assign a parent post to each post.

For an example you can test immediately, the built-in `post` post type in WordPress is non-hierarchical, the built-in `page` post type is hierarchical.

You can make a custom post type hierarchical by setting the `hierarchical` argument to `true` when you register the post type. You also need to add `page-attributes` to the `supports` argument when you register your post type, so that you will have the meta box that allows you to select a parent for each post.

In this scheme, you will first create custom *posts* for each of your categories, `facelift`, `liposuction`, etc.. You can then create the individual child `patient-1` posts and assign the appropriate parent to each.

WordPress will allow these posts to have non-unique slugs because each will have a unique parent. This works because "behind the scenes" these posts are being queried by the full parent/child path, so WP is able to differentiate the ones with non-unique slugs.