# How to display category and subcategory in wordpress permalink structure?

Tags: permalinks

I have permalink structure like:

```
example.com/category/sub-category/postname
```

it is working, but while using another sub category under same category with same post name it shows

```
example.com/category/sub-category/postname-2
```

what's the problem?

I am using `/%category%/%postname%/` as permalink structure

Comment: You cannot have same slug for two post even if they belong to some other sub category. So you can change `postname-2` to some other slug but not `postname` again.

Comment: Check this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/201852/allow-duplicate-slugs-for-posts-on-custom-post-type-in-different-categories-taxo

Comment: my problem is i have course category which contains degree, pg sub categories

Comment: here see example.com/course/degree/maths and another url is example.com/course/pg/maths but is shows example.com/course/pg/maths-2

Comment: Wordpress doesn't allow duplicate slug by default although the post belongs to different category or post type unless hierarchical. So you need to use a hierarchical post type as mentioned in the link that I've shared previously. So to have two posts as `/degree/maths` and `/pg/maths` you can use hierarchical post type.

Comment: is there any solution for this. i want permalink structure like this

Comment: Are you using default `post` or custom post type?

Comment: i am using default post type of wordpress

Comment: can any one help me